# Round ionicTimePicker to nearest 30 minute interval

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

What is the best way to round the inputTime component in [ionicTimePicker](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker) to the nearest 30 minute interval?

I have a strong feeling that this has to be changed:

`inputTime: ((new Date()).getHours() * 60 * 60 + (new Date()).getMinutes() * 60),`

For example:

```
If current time is 15:17, then return 15:30
If current time is 15:45, then return 16:00
```

My code so far:

```
$scope.openTimePicker = function () {
  var timePickerObject = {
    step: 30, //Optional
    callback: function (val) {
      if (typeof (val) === 'undefined') {
        console.log('Time not selected');
      } else {
        var selectedTime = new Date(val * 1000);
        console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selectedTime.getUTCHours(), 'H :', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'M');
      }
    },
    inputTime: ((new Date()).getHours() * 60 * 60 + (new Date()).getMinutes() * 60),
    format: 24
  };
  ionicTimePicker.openTimePicker(timePickerObject);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a rounding function like this:

```
function getRoundedTime() {
    var d = new Date(); 
    var ratio = d.getMinutes() / 60;
    // Past 30 min mark, return epoch at +1 hours and 0 minutes
    if(ratio > 0.5){
        return (d.getHours() + 1) * 3600;
    }
    // Before 30 minute mark, return epoch at 0 minutes
    if(ratio < 0.5) {
         return d.getHours() * 3600;
    }
    // Right on the 30 minute mark, return epoch at 30 minutes
    return (d.getHours() * 3600) + 1800;
}
```

I tried to match the "epoch" format given by `((new Date()).getHours() * 60 * 60 + (new Date()).getMinutes() * 60)`

Here you can see some test outputs:

```js
function getRoundedTime(inDate) {
        var d = new Date(); 
        if(inDate) {
          d = inDate;
        }
        var ratio = d.getMinutes() / 60;
        // Past 30 min mark, return epoch at +1 hours and 0 minutes
        if(ratio > 0.5){
            return (d.getHours() + 1) * 3600;
        }
        // Before 30 minute mark, return epoch at 0 minutes
        if(ratio < 0.5) {
             return d.getHours() * 3600;
        }
        // Right on the 30 minute mark, return epoch at 30 minutes
        return (d.getHours() * 3600) + 1800;
}

var a = new Date();
var b = new Date();
var c = new Date();
a.setMinutes(29);
b.setMinutes(30);
c.setMinutes(31);

var aNode = document.createTextNode("Time at " + a.getMinutes() + " minutes yields: " + getRoundedTime(a) + ", ");
var bNode = document.createTextNode("Time at " + b.getMinutes() + " minutes yields: " + getRoundedTime(b) + ", ");
var cNode = document.createTextNode("Time at " + c.getMinutes() + " minutes yields: " + getRoundedTime(c));

var target = document.getElementById("t");
target.appendChild(aNode);
target.appendChild(bNode);
target.appendChild(cNode);
```

```html
<div id="t">
  
</div>
```

If you always want to round up to the nearest half-hour, remove the "before 30 minute mark" conditional, so you end up with:

```
function getRoundedTime() {
    var d = new Date(); 
    var ratio = d.getMinutes() / 60;
    // Past 30 min mark, return epoch at +1 hours and 0 minutes
    if(ratio > 0.5){
        return (d.getHours() + 1) * 3600;
    }
    // Return epoch at 30 minutes past current hour
    return (d.getHours() * 3600) + 1800;
}
```

Comment: I added a correction to the 30 minute mark case, changed `+ 30` to `+ (30 * 60)` or `+ 1800`

Comment: Thanks. As I am using this for an appointment booking system, I was just wondering how I can make the use case for `Before 30 minute mark` return the epoch at 30 minutes instead of at 0 minutes (as it is not possible to book an appointment in the past). I tried combining it with the `Right on the 30 minute mark` use case but it returns the epoch at 1 hour 30 mins for some reason. In a nutshell, I only want it to round UP to the nearest 30 mins and never down.

Comment: @methuselah I've added code to my answer with the conditional that rounds down removed. The new block of code always rounds up to the half hour, either by returning the current hour at 30 minutes or the next hour when past 30 minutes.